# RestorationMixin state disappear

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying restore my state after I close my Apps, when using the debug mode with don't keep activities, the apps runs normally and state of the apps restored. But after I swipe the apps from the switch apps menu, the state is gone.

I want to restore the state apps after closing the apps from the switch apps menu. Can someone explain how restoration mixin works? thank you.

Comment: Specify your question more. Otherwise, just search and read the documentation. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RestorationMixin-mixin.html

Comment: give a try,, then you can show your effort solving on specific usecase

Comment: okaay thank you @RobertSandberg I'll check the documentation and do some googling, I think I missed something when I read the documentation.